# Google Project Tango: Geometry won't show up?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, but I can't find anywhere else. let me know if there's somewhere else more appropriate.

Anyway, I'm just starting to work with Google Project Tango. I'm just testing, so I've set everything up as Google's guide asked, and placed a simple cube in the scene. It built and installed on the device just fine, and the tracking and everything works, but no geometry shows up.

I've tried a lot of things, changing settings, changing geometry, changing cameras entirely. But none of that has worked. I just can't get any geometry to show up.

Anyone have any idea of what might be causing this? I don't get any errors either... Bleh.

Thanks for your help!
-Ally

Comment: Hi Ally, which API you are using? By change setting, geometry, camera, do you mean change them in code?

Comment: What do you mean by geometry?